# How do I control the size of the connection pool in pyodbc?

Tags: python, database-connection, connection-pooling, pyodbc

The pyodbc connection pool is set to true by default, but I don't see anything in the [documentation](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/api.html) about controlling the size of the connection pool. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server? This is usually controlled on the DB side.